# Condition for conditional split transformation

Tags: ssis

Hi I am trying to conditional spit data in flat file where i have column called modified date there are errors in data. I want send those error data to a flat file and remaining to table in database. I am trying out for the condition in the conditional split transformation. Please help me out .
 The correct data looks: 
2006-08-01 00:00:00,2006-08-01 00:00:00
2006-09-01 00:00:00,2006-09-01 00:00:00
2006-07-01 00:00:00,2006-07-01 00:00:00

incorrect data:
2008-01-22 10:09:29.423000000
2008-01-22 10:09:29.423000000

Comment: What makes the incorrect data incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading a text file, if the column is text, you can do this - LEN( [Line1]) > 19

You might also want to consider that the data is not bad.  It looks like it has greater precision.  If you change the data type in the destination it might work for all records.